# Having issue in my htacces?static hyperlink It is working.If I changed to dynamic It is not working

Tags: .htaccess

Having issue in my htaccess file? Static hyperlink It is working.If I changed to  dynamic hyperlink the rule is not working.I don't know what is wrong in htaccess file.I know only plain php.my objective is I don't want to show the .php extension any where in the whole website.can any one tell what is the wrong in dynamic hyperlink. See the url also http://rang.comli.com/ then click service,tuiton the url is working fine.under dynamic click edit.The url is not coming like static.can any one guide me what I have to write properly in htaccess file.

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+servicecnt\.php\?service_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ servicecnt/service_id/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+tuition\.php\?tuition_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ tuition/tuition_id/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+edit\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ edit/id/%1? [R=302,L]


RewriteRule ^servicecnt/service_id/(\d+)/?$ servicecnt.php?service_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^tuition/tuition_id/(\d+)/?$ tuition.php?tuition_id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^edit/id/(\d+)/?$ edit.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

myform:

```
<p style="padding-left:200px; color:red"> static link
<a  href="http://rang.comli.com/servicecnt/service_id/5">Service</a>
<a  href="http://rang.comli.com/tuition.php/tuition_id/5">Tuition</a></p>
<div align="center">
<form name="nschool" action="" method="post">
<table cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td height="44"></td>
<td>Titlte</td>
<td><input type="text" name="title"/></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="49"></td>
<td>News</td>
<td><textarea name="news"></textarea></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="padding-left:50px;"><input type="submit" name="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
<p style="color:#FF0000;">Dyanmic link</p>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from school");
while($exe=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
?>
<Tr>
<td width="200"><?php echo $exe['title'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</td>
<td width="200"><?php echo $exe['news'];?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</td>
<Td width="88"><a href="http://rang.comli.com/edit/id/<?php echo $exe['id'];?>">Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</Td>
<Td width="169"><a href="?mode=delete&id=<?php echo $exe['id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete')"">D</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</Td>
</Tr>
<?php 
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is `http://rang.comli.com/edit/id/10` is giving 302 to `http://error404.000webhost.com/?` Try adding `ErrorDocument 404 default ` at top of your htaccess

Comment: ok I will do that why this is not coming in proper way.as per your suggestion I have written everything.I think you solve this problem.

Comment: Is `/edit/` a directory? Does it have a .htaccess also?

Comment: edit is a edit.php page? to edit the profile after user login. not directory.

Comment: Add `Options -MultiViews` also on top of .htaccess

Comment: yes It is working you can check this  link http://rang.comli.com/ then click edit.This website has only three category.parent,child,sub child category.I am planing to bring dynamic menu with category,subcategory.maximum this site have 15menus and gallery,profile, and multiple search,sms api integration,facebook api,I believe with plain php and htaccess file I can the develop the this website.further i won't show the .php extension. is it possible with plain php and htaccess.say your suggestion in future i will learn mvc.

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible with the help of .htaccess without using any MVC framework. I will post an answer here to help other visitors on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these 2 lines on top of your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: one final query how to make if the page is in directory for tuition is the directory page is tuition.php?t_id=5. and if you explain me how to write rewrite condition and rewrite rule.only one step is enough for me remaining I will learn.if you explain me it is great experience and knowledge for me.

Comment: What is the exact URL do you want support for `tuition`?

Comment: <a href="/chennai/class-xi-xii-home-tuitions-classes">Class XI-XII</a>
<a href="/chennai/bsc-home-tuitions-classes">BSc Tuition </a>  don't forget to give explanation and every thing is dynamic.that why i asked dynamic id anchor tag. In admin part bsc home tuitions. I want to replace with space to - for your knowledge I am saying.I will do this in htaccess or str_replace in php.

Comment: ok now I think it is better to create a new question now since `/chennai/class-xi-xii-home-tuitions-classes` doesn't have `tuition_id` value in it. And asking questions via comments is not liked by SO moderators.

Comment: ok i will do this.explain me how to write rewrite condition and rewrite rule.only one step is enough for me remaining I will learn

Comment: Yes sure I will explain the rules in my answer to your new question.